# Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

im trying to upload my first wordpress website. Im using the local wordpress.org php my admin and the php my admin from 000webhost. Ive researched this a a lot here and changed all the settings people were saying from utf8mb4 to utf8 but it only caused more errors. I changed everything back to what it was (at least i think so and the error is the same as the beginning now). Anyone knows how i can get around this and import my db to 000.webhost with no errors? the Error is SQL query:

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

and

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The first: If you can control ssh server. Please update mysql version. Your mysql too old. Maybe `< 5.5.3`.

2) The second: If you can't access ssh. Try to export your database with `Mysql version 4.0`.

- With command line `mysqldump --compatible=mysql40 -u user -p DB > dumpfile.sql`
- With web access `phpmyadmin` -> Select Database -> Export -> Custom - display all possible options -> Format-specific options ->

  Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with: Select `MYSQL40`.
- Change content file .sql you exported

`/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8mb4 */ ;`

to `utf8` only.

And replace by Ctrl H in Sublime change all from `utf8mb4` => `utf8`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MárioSouto If you can update your mysql. Just update it. If can't, read 2).

Comment: i changed the export option to mysql40 but when importing to 000webhost it gives me the same exact error as before.

Comment: @MárioSouto     Change content file .sql you exported

`/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8mb4 */ ;`

to `utf8` only.

Comment: You changed to `utf8` only and it still don't work? @MárioSouto

Comment: 2nd didnt work too. i changed to /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */; and got this:
SQL query:

-- Estrutura da tabela `wp_commentmeta`
--
CREATE TABLE  `wp_commentmeta` (

 `meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
 `comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `meta_value` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

and 

MySQL said: Documentation

#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

Comment: @MárioSouto The first, remove exist database in your hosting. The next replace by Ctrl H in Sublime change all from `utf8mb4` => `utf8`. And import database again.

Comment: ok replaced it all but gotta wait a bit till the 000webhost lets me in again. i deleted the previous db cause it had 2 tables created and created a new one and its giving me the same error as yesteday, i think i just have to wait a bit till it lets me in.

Comment: @MárioSouto Okay let me know if you still can't import it.

Comment: ok its working thanks. but all unformated for some reason thanks anyway.

Comment: @MárioSouto With Wordpress you must change site_url and home_url in table _option. And after that use plugins Velvet change URL site for change to new domain. It's will worked.

Comment: i already changed the site_url on the 000webhost options. it worked for like 5mins than it goes down again saying "No site configured at this address".
can only enter in the http://www.webdesignerms.netau.net/wp-admin/ but if i click visit website it gives the same error

Comment: @MárioSouto Maybe DNS have problems. You point DNS to 000webhost long time ago or just change it? And 000webhost is free hosting right?

Comment: @MárioSouto Just connect when you want edit/update/delete file in hosting xD Btw please buy one VPS installed LAMP have full controll access. It's the best way to learn coding. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just modify this into mysql Database.
wrong that modify .....     /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

now corrected .....          /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
just erase  ....  mb4  ....

its work now

Comment: Does it though? Any multibyte characters supported by utf8mb4 that are not supported by utf8 will show up as gibberish